# How to parse object in the soap response in Blackberry

Tags: parsing, soap, blackberry, blackberry-10, momentics

I am New to blackberry Develipment.I am developing using Momentics IDE. Now I am working on Soap webservice integration. Now my webservice function call is working. I am getting response also. My webservice response is like,

```
 <SignupResponse xmlns="http://shidhints.com/">
      <SignupResult>
        <Success>boolean</Success>
        <ErrorOnFailure>string</ErrorOnFailure>
        <Token>string</Token>
        <NumberofReferral>int</NumberofReferral>
        <ListEmails>
          <string>string</string>
          <string>string</string>
        </ListEmails>
      </SignupResult>
  </SignupResponse>
```

While parese the responce, Now I can parse and get the **Token**, **NumberofReferral** But I cannot parse the **ListEmails** object. How I can parse this **ListEmails**. I am doing like this.

```
m_Token = responseValue["Token"].value().toString();
m_NumberofReferral = responseValue["NumberofReferral"].value().toString();
QVariantList listObj = responseValue["ListEmails"].value().toList();
```

Now I want to parse **listObj** How i can do that,

Comment: I'm pretty sure we'd need more information than that. Ie, what are you using to parse the data. I think you should have a look at `SaxParser`, it would come in handy.

Comment: @Kelvin :  I am using C++ for Blackberry development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it using

```
QtSoapArray &m_Emails1 = (QtSoapArray &) responseValue["ListEmails"];
for (int var = 0; var < m_Emails1.count(); ++var) {
        qDebug() << "Email: "+ m_Emails1[var].toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    responseValue["ListEmails"]
```

That element contains multiple values, so you'll get a [`QVariant`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/qvariant.html) wrapping a [`QVariantList`](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/qvariant.html#QVariantList-typedef) .

More info:
http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/data_access/working_with_xml.html
http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__data__xmldataaccess.html